# SSL form action issue - Zoo Visitor

Tags: zoo-visitor

I am using the Zoo Visitor login form within a secured environment and the form action being output is **http://** instead of **https://** - even when I put a full path like: `return="https://www.site-name.com/account"` the form action is: `action="http://www.site-name.com/account"`.

How can I make the form submit to a secure URL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `secure_action="yes"` and `secure_return="yes"` [parameters from safecracker](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#secure-action) in the Zoo Visitor login form tag. There's a [Zoo Visitor support post](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/6993) on Devot:ee. I've also tried this on my own Zoo Visitor login form and can confirm that it works.